# R merging Partial match

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

there are a lot of answers about that, but I didn't find out with the problem that I am handle.

I have 2 dataframes:

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

```
setA <- read.table("df1.txt",sep="\t", header=TRUE)
setB <- read.table("df2.txt",sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

So, I want the matching rows by column value:

```
library(data.table)
setC <-merge(setA, setB, by.x = "name", by.y = "name", all.x = FALSE)
```

And I get this output:

df3:

[image]

Because in df I have also de value 1, but separete with a ";". How can I get the desire output?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In future please apply the function dput(df1) and dput(df2) and copy and paste the output from the console into your question.

Base R solution to two part question:

```
# First unstack the 1;7 row into two separate rows: 

name_split <- strsplit(df1$name, ";")

# If the values of last vector uniquely identify each row in the dataframe: 

df_ro <- data.frame(name = unlist(name_split),
                     last = rep(df1$last, sapply(name_split, length)),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Left join to achieve the same result as first solution 
# without specifically naming each vector: 

df1_ro <- merge(df1[,names(df1) != "name"], df_ro, by = "last", all.x = TRUE)

# Then perform an inner join preventing a name space collision: 

df3 <- merge(df1_ro, setNames(df2, paste0(names(df2), ".x")),
             by.x = "name", by.y = "name.x")

# If you wanted to perform an inner join on all intersecting columns (returning
# no results because values in last and colour are different then): 

df3 <- merge(df1_ro, df2, by = intersect(names(df1_ro), names(df2)))
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("1;7", "3", "4", "5"),
                  last = c("p", "q", "r", "s"),
                  colour = c("a", "s", "d", "f"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                  last = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                  colour = c("p", "q", "r", "s"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry for the format. The point is to scalable this script for big data files that contains a lot of columns, so I would like to know if exits another way to avoid to define the header of each column

Comment: @WindSur please see edited solution and mark it as correct if you found it useful. Note, you will have to repeat the values for as many vectors (read columns) in your dataframe as it takes to uniquely identify each row (not including the "name" vector). Does this make sense ?

Comment: @WindSur Please accept my solution if you found it to answer your question or I am happy to answer any further questions you may have.

Answer (score -1):

At the end I achieved with this solution:

```
co=open('NewFile.txt','w')
f=open('IndexFile.txt','r')
g=open('File.txt','r')

tabla1 = f.readlines()
tabla2 = g.readlines()

B=[]
for ln in tabla1:
    B = ln.split('\t')[3]
    for k, ln2 in enumerate(tabla2):
        if B in ln2.split('\t')[3]:
            xx=ln2
            print(xx)
            co.write(xx)
            break
co.close()
```

Comment: This is Python not R (as is requested in the question),  please refer to my solution below.